# error CloudKit access was denied by user settings when user is not sign in

Tags: ios, xcode6, icloud, cloudkit

I'm trying to get fetch the notification of changes in the public database:

```
CKServerChangeToken *token = [[cloudKitToken helper] getCloudKitToken];
CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation *op = [[CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation alloc]
                                           initWithPreviousServerChangeToken:token];
NSMutableArray *noteIds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

op.notificationChangedBlock = ^(CKNotification *note) {
    CKNotificationID *noteId = note.notificationID;
    [noteIds addObject:noteId];

};

op.fetchNotificationChangesCompletionBlock = ^(CKServerChangeToken *token, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"error %@", error.localizedDescription);
};

[[CKContainer defaultContainer] addOperation:op];
```

But when the user has not login to iCloud I get this error: "error CloudKit access was denied by user settings"

By another hand with the same device I can fetch records from the public database with no problem.

What I'm trying to do with the CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation is get the deltas between device and cloudkit.

Any of you knows how can I get the deltas when the user has not login to iCloud?, does fetch records is my only option for this case?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

With CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation you can retrieve all the notifications that were send to you since a previous fetch. These notifications are linked to subscriptions that you previously created for a device. Subscriptions are linked to an account. So you must be logged in with the same account in order to fetch these notifications.

In your case you might be better of by using CKFetchRecordChangesOperation. Then you would be able to just query for CloudKit changes since a previous query. Since it's just a query using a 'server change token'. The first time you can query it with nil and then retrieve all the records. you would get a 'server change token' in return. just save that on the device and the next time you start the app just use that token. Then there would be no need to log in to iCloud. (if your data is public)